# how to save data from a nativeTextField to sqlite database in corona

Tags: coronasdk

Having a hard time saving data from a native text field to sqlite database in corona.

here are some relevant code:

```
    function printrecord()
        for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM test") do
           t = display.newText(row.pname .. " " .. row.age .. " " .. row.desc, 20, 30 * row.id, null, 16)
           t:setTextColor(255,255,255)
        end
    end

    newData = native.newTextField ( 20, _H - 90, 280, 30 )
    newData.inputType = "text"

    saveData = function ( event )
        textString = newData.text
        db:exec( [[ INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, textString, 30, "unknown")]] )
        t:removeSelf()
        t = nil
        printrecord()
    end

    savebutton = widget.newButton {
        default = "buttonGreen.png",
        over = "buttonGreenOver.png",
        label = "Save",
        embose = true,
        onRelease = saveData
        }
```

when I try to change the `textString` from `db:exec( [[ INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, textString, 30, "unknown")]] )` to a string like "this is a string" it seems to work fine, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua will not evaluate textString inside the double brackets... Run this in Corona to see the difference:

```
textString="hello world"


print([[ INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, textString, 30, "unknown")]])

print([[ INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL,"]]..textString..[[",30,"unknown")]])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Already figured this one out awhile ago, thanks for the help anyway.